# Is reckless driving combined with open container a CIMT that can lead to deportation in the USA?

Tags: student-visa, usa, criminal-records

I am an F1 student in the USA and recently entered a guilty plea for reckless driving and open container. Is this combination considered a CIMT that can lead to deportation? This is my first and only offence in the US in 10 years as a student. I got sentenced to one year of probation with DUI classes and 10 days of work alternative.

I know that reckless driving on its own or open container on its own is not CIMT (at least I think so) and neither is full DUI even if it involves injuries to people. But my concern is about the combination of the two.